# Access Update Query: Id Matches, and Date is between date in two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

Good afternoon all,

I'm working on a project to update historical pricing in an Access 2010 database. I have an update query in which the transaction list has the product id, the date it was sold, and the wholesale of that transaction.

I have a second table that has the product id with the start date column, end date column, and the wholesale value of the product at that time.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
UPDATE
    [Copy Of MFRM_SALES_DATA]
LEFT JOIN
    [Pricing over Time]
ON
    [Copy Of MFRM_SALES_DATA].VSN = [Pricing over Time].[Product Value]

SET [Copy Of MFRM_SALES_DATA].Upd_Wholesale =
    IIF
    (
            [Copy Of MFRM_SALES_DATA].[dt]>[Pricing over Time].[Start Date]
        AND [Copy Of MFRM_SALES_DATA].[dt]<[Pricing over Time].[End Date],
        [pricing over time].[value]
    );
```

The table naming could be cleaner but lets focus on the task. When I run this, it returns UPD_Wholesale with blanks all the way down the column (about 1.2m rows).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Rich

Comment: Your `IIf()` is missing the `falsepart` argument. I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Note: http://www.sqlinform.com/sql_formatter_online.html helps with SQL formatting.

Comment: @Andre with the ,0 for false, it still throws up the same result. Thanks for the formatting tool.

Comment: Should your date range be inclusive? i.e. sold_date >= StartDate ... <= EndDate? And what value do you want to use if there were no Star/End records for price?

Comment: Do you have two columns for values in [Pricing over Time] [value] would give a blank if the actual data is in [Product Value]. Also: Check, that the field types of the dates match.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, I went through and added a start/end date for every value. Double checked. Also, the field types do match.

Comment: @Johanness - the naming is not 100% what i'd like it to be but [pricing over time].[value] is the product cost and [pricing over time].[product value] is the product id.

Comment: Have you tried to change your query to a 'select' query, then run the sql manually to see if you can find the problem?

Comment: I assume, you have multiple matches for the same product ID. Try creating a new table which has all the data first. That should give you a better approach for the problem.

Comment: If you have multiple items on both sides of a left join, you cannot control which one is checked last - so could it be, that every link was updated multiple times and the last update was not with the correct date, so the update was: upda_Wholesale=IIF(false,value,NOTHING) which results to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

YOur problem may stem from multiple values on both sides of the JOIN. What you want to do is link exactly one product to any sale:

```
UPDATE
    [Copy Of MFRM_SALES_DATA]
LEFT JOIN
    [Pricing over Time]
ON
    [Copy Of MFRM_SALES_DATA].VSN = [Pricing over Time].[Product Value] AND
    [Copy Of MFRM_SALES_DATA].[dt]>[Pricing over Time].[Start Date] AND
    [Copy Of MFRM_SALES_DATA].[dt]<[Pricing over Time].[End Date],

SET 
    [Copy Of MFRM_SALES_DATA].Upd_Wholesale = [pricing over time].[value];
```